# UFW is blocking DNS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dns, ufw

I am configuring the security in my server. For easier the manage at the firewall, I installed the UFW. I did some settings in the UFW and I allowed some ports. Therefor when I enabled it the DNS services not responding.

I tried running the command `DIG www.domain.com.br` to test the DNS but it did not succeed. This command run without problems when the UFW is disabled. I already allowed the 53 port (TCP and UDP) but the DNS does not work.

My UFW settings:

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), deny (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
21/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
16/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
53                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
465                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
25/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
21/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
16/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
53 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
465 (v6)                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
25/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
22 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Comment: Post the output of `ufw status verbose`...

Comment: Here is the output http://pastebin.com/31Asbqwb

Comment: I tried it but it did not work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I solved this problem. I allowed the outgoing for port 53 that is DNS service port.
Thanks.

```
sudo ufw allow out 53
```

Answer (score 15):

The full correct syntax should be

```
sudo ufw allow out to any port 53
```

Answer (score 5):

Firstly `ufw allow dns` allows ingoing DNS requests, which is not what you want.

Secondly you can follow all commands mentioned in other answers (most easily `ufw allow out 53`), but **order matters**. So if you have a deny statement, which would also deny DNS requests when used solely, **put it last**!

So first allow port 53 to your DNS server and later potentially disallow/deny some requests.

Answer (score 3):

I've been working on some firewall rules myself for another project and wasn't able to get @diegoklapper's solution to work.

Even my own attempts to replicate `sudo ufw allow dns` more explicitly (i.e. specific interface) failed:

`sudo ufw allow in on eth0 from any to any port 53 proto tcp`

Until I realized what I was doing wrong (note protocol):

`sudo ufw allow in on eth0 from any to any port 53 proto udp`

Note: This more specifically applies to `dnsmasq` in the case where you're handling or forwarding DNS requests and where outbound requests are already allowed by default.

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
53/udp on eth0             ALLOW IN    Anywhere
```