# UFW blocks hostname lookup on LAN for ssh and ping

Tags: ssh, ping, hostname, ufw, lan

I'm experiencing a problem connecting to hosts on my LAN via their hostname only when UFW is enabled.

When UFW is **enabled**:

- `ssh <machine>` gives the message:

  ```
  ssh: Could not resolve hostname <machine>: Name or service not known
  ```
- `ssh <machine-ip>` connects just fine.
- `ping <machine>` gives the message:

  ```
  ping: <machine>: Name or service not known
  ```
- `ping <machine-ip>` works.

When UFW is **disabled**:

- `ssh <machine>` connects just fine.
- `ping <machine>` works just fine.

If I lookup for hosts' names manually with `nmap -sP 192.168.14.1/24` I can see all the hosts on my LAN with UFW enabled / disabled.

I read this question: "[UFW is blocking DNS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131332/ufw-is-blocking-dns)" and it's answers and I think it' irrelevant because UFW is not installed nor enabled on the remote machines I'm trying to connect to.

I `allow`ed with `ufw` the app `DNS` as suggested by [@rugk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/146739/rugk)'s [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/352221/135796) and I also tried to do what the other answers proposed but it didn't help.

Do I need to manually enter the known hosts' IP addresses in `/etc/hosts`? I would prefer to avoid it because I'm using a laptop which isn't always connected to this specific network.

Comment: What is output of `ufw status numbered`?  What DNS server are the clients using to resolve those names?  Does other name resolution work?

Comment: In `ufw status numbered` I can see that the `DNS` app is allowed. As for your 2nd question, I think that the DNS server the clients are usually using to resolve those names is `192.168.14.1` - it is stated in `/etc/resolv.conf` which is managed by `systemd-resolved(8)`. `/etc/resolv.conf` is linked to `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` as explained in the [Arch Linux Wiki page on systemd-networkd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-networkd#Basic_DHCP_network)